# JavaScript Regex for checking invalid characters for excel sheet name

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a regex for checking these 7 characters ('/', '', '[', ']', '*', ':', '?') in any order as long as there is at least one character exists in the string. I tried using the [Regex Generator](https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/) and it output this expression :*.[*.]*.\/*? but it doesn't work.

Comment: try `[\/\[\]:?*]*`

Comment: Just `/[\/\\[\]*:?]/`, you need a *character class*.

Comment: [\/\[\]:?*]* it returns true even if there is no character exists in the string

Comment: i tried this one /[\/\\[\]*:?]/ but it returns true on '\' character

Comment: what is that 2nd and 4th characters?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
/[\[\]\/:?'"]/g
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/12E3q0/1)

Hope this helps!